# Print pattern using for loop and return method

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, methods, return

I am trying to print

```
             a
             bb
             ccc
             dddd
```

The code I have is not doing the pattern I would like and not sure where the issue is at. Any help would be great.

```
public static String generatRowOfSymbols(char letterOne, char letterTwo){

        char i;
        char j;

        String letters = "";
        String row = "";

        for(i=letterOne; i<= letterTwo; i++  ){


            for(j=letterOne; j<=i; j++){

            row += i ;

            }

            letters += row + "\n";

        }


        return letters;
```

Comment: the Pattern is a (next line) bb (next line) ccc (next line) dddd (next line)

Comment: Why is `j` looping from `letterOne`? Shouldn't it just be some kind of counter? Also, you don't reset `row` to empty.

Comment: Having J set as letterOne let me print out abbcccdddd in a line so it worked for that. The issue is getting the other pattern in a half triangle.

Answer (score 0):

First, use a StringBuilder -- it's faster and more efficient.  I didn't calculate the length, but if you want to, you can.  Second, take a look at the changes I made to your method and let me know if it doesn't make sense.  Please note that I'm using the System's line separator -- if you really want to append '\n', please do so.

As you should see, our first for-loop walks through the letters.  The second, which is nested, prints out `count` letters, which increments by one each time that we change the letter.

```
public static String generatRowOfSymbols(char letterOne, char letterTwo) {
    StringBuilder letters = new StringBuilder();

    int count = 1;
    for (char i = letterOne; i <= letterTwo; i++, count++) {
        StringBuilder row = new StringBuilder(count);
        for (int j = 0; j < count; j++) {
            row.append(i);
        }

        letters.append(row).append(System.lineSeparator());
    }
    return letters.toString();
}
```

---

### Edit

Here's yours fixed using Strings instead of StringBuilder, since there is a hesitation to use StringBuilder.

```
public static String generatRowOfSymbols(char letterOne, char letterTwo) {
    String letters = "";

    int count = 1;
    for (char i = letterOne; i <= letterTwo; i++, count++) {
        String row = "";
        for (int j = 0; j < count; j++) {
            row +=i ;
        }

        letters += row + System.lineSeparator();
    }
    return letters;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Dan. I have never used String builder but it does look neat. I know I can complete the desired pattern in a way similar to what I have already but I am missing something simple.Thank again

Comment: Using String is the exact same code that I posted, just instead of calls to .append you'd do your String concatenation.

Comment: Do you see the code in my edit, then?  Please note that you made several mistakes in your code.  If you look, I moved `row` into the first for-loop -- this is critical the way that you are using it.  You'll also note that I've changed what `j` is and added a count.  This is also an important difference between your and my code.  I don't know who downvoted my answer, but if you plug in either of my code blocks, it prints out just the way that you said you wanted.

Comment: Also, if you didn't know, String is immutable -- "appending" makes a new String Object... that's why StringBuilder is more efficient.

Comment: Hi Dan. Thanks for the help but the issue turned out to be very simple. I just needed to get rid of row and have letter += "\n" on the second loop.

Answer (score 0):

public static String generatRowOfSymbols(char letterOne, char letterTwo){

```
    char i;
    char j;

    String letters = "";



    for(i=letterOne; i<= letterTwo; i++  ){


        for(j=letterOne; j<=i; j++){

        letters +=i;

        }

        letters+= "\n";

    }


    return letters;
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution that I can come up with is as follows. I used IntStream but you can easily change it to a for-loop; the logic is the same.

```
public static void printPattern(int rows) {
    IntStream.range(0, rows).forEach(x -> {
        IntStream.range(0, x + 1).forEach(y -> {
            System.out.print((char) ('a' + x));
        });
        System.out.println();
    });
}
```

Suppose, we use it as follows.

```
printPattern(10);
```

Output:

```
a
bb
ccc
dddd
eeeee
ffffff
ggggggg
hhhhhhhh
iiiiiiiii
jjjjjjjjjj
```